# persist list<long[]> in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to persist my list with a number of channels and their timestamps on to my database, but I still haven't found a way to do it. I tried it with serialization and with creating a JSON string but both way weren't successful for me. How would you persist a list like that in hibernate?

EDIT: This is the part of the code where I try to persist the list by persisting every channel. Right now I save them as byte[] but this doesn't work. When I try to deserialize the byte[] I don't get my list. I also tried to save them as long[] and type the columns as bigint[] but this didn't work either.

```
@Entity
public class RecordingEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "channel_one")
    private byte[] channelOneAsByteArray;

    @Column(name = "channel_two")
    private byte[] channelTwoAsByteArray;

    @Column(name = "channel_three")
    private byte[] channelThreeAsByteArray;
    ...
    public RecordingEntity(List<Long[]> recordingList, File rawFile, Recording recording)
    {
        this.recording = recording;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try
        {
            rawFileAsByteArray = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(rawFile);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        setRecordingList(recordingList);
    }
    ...
    public List<Long[]> getRecordingList()
    {
        List<Trigger[]> recordingList = new ArrayList<>();
        int channels = recording.getChannels();
        Long[] channelOne = (Long[]) SerializationUtils.deserialize(channelOneAsByteArray);
        Long[] channelTwo = (Long[]) SerializationUtils.deserialize(channelTwoAsByteArray);
        Long[] channelThree = (Long[]) SerializationUtils.deserialize(channelThreeAsByteArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < channelOneAsByteArray.length; i++)
        {
            Long[] positionArray = new Long[channels];
            if (0 < channels)
            {
                positionArray[0] = channelOne[I];
            }
            if (1 < channels)
            {
                positionArray[1] = channelTwo[I];
            }
            if (2 < channels)
            {
                positionArray[2] = channelThree[I];
            }
            recordingList.add(positionArray);
        }
        return recordingList;
    } 
    ...
    public void setRecordingList(List<Long[]> recordingList)
    {
        int channels = recording.getChannels();

        long[] channelOne = new long[recordingList.size()];
        long[] channelTwo = new long[recordingList.size()];
        long[] channelThree = new long[recordingList.size()];
        for (Long[] positionArray : recordingList)
        {
            int index = 0;
            if (0 < channels)
            {
                channelOne[index] = positionArray[0];
            }
            if (1 < channels)
            {
                channelTwo[index] = positionArray[1];
            }
            if (2 < channels)
            {
                channelThree[index] = positionArray[2];
            }
            index++;
        }
        channelOneAsByteArray = SerializationUtils.serialize(channelOne);
        channelTwoAsByteArray = SerializationUtils.serialize(channelTwo);
        channelThreeAsByteArray = SerializationUtils.serialize(channelThree);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you imagine that in the database? Like a table that contains the link for the list and a second table that holds the actual values?

Comment: I would prefer to have the list in one column as one entry or a column for every channel (max number of channels are 3). Every Channel would have his own array. I tried to persist a long[] but the type is bytea or something else in the database. I tried to use bigint[] as a type but I get an error message when persisting the long[].

Comment: You should really post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it with batch insertion only.